# Get route query params

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, angular2-routing

I am trying to migrate from rc1 to rc4 and i have trouble getting query string parameters. ActivatedRoute object always empty.

**hero.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Control} from "@angular/common";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template: '../partials/main.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _activatedRoute: activatedRoute) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params);
        });
    }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {AppRouterProviders} from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    AppRouterProviders,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HeroComponent} from './hero.component';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '../partials/main.html',
    directives: [
        HeroComponent,
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ]
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

**partials/main.html**

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{st: 'new'}">New</a>
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig}  from '@angular/router';
import {HeroComponent} from './hero.component';
import {ErrorComponent} from './error.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path:'', component: HeroComponent},
    {path:'**', component: ErrorComponent}
];

export const AppRouterProviders = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

When i click on link 'New' console prints out empty object

> Object {}

**Updated**

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s5tYzWmbOXZRiRdunF4N?p=preview)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**update (2.0.0 final)**

(`somepath/:someparam/someotherpath`) you can subscribe to them using `_router.queryParams.subscribe(...)`:

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _router:Router) {
    _activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
      params => console.log('queryParams', params['st']));
```

**original**

If you want `queryParams` instead of route params (`somepath/:someparam/someotherpath`) you can subscribe to them using `_router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(...)`:

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _router:Router) {
    _router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(
      params => console.log('queryParams', params['st']));
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KVCoN9qmavi6ckYTplkH?p=preview)

Comment: I like your answer and it works as expected, but you maybe know why did I get empty ActivatedRoute object in my plunker example? Just curious.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean with "empty"? `ActivatedRoute` is passed in, otherwise `.params.subscribe()` would throw.

Comment: The ActivatedRoute itself should contain query params about activated component but i get empty object when I subscribe . Dont know how to clarify better.

Comment: Can you please post an updated Plunker with a `console.log(...)` that prints the empty object you're talking about?

Comment: My plunker example can already shows you this. Check http://plnkr.co/edit/s5tYzWmbOXZRiRdunF4N?p=preview and open the console and see the output.

Comment: But there is no parameter on initial load. You Plunker doesn't use `params` at all. The `New` link uses `queryParams` but that is only passed after the link is clicked.

Comment: It seems RouterState does no longer have a property queryParams https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterState-interface.html

Comment: Thanks @CarloRoosen. `_activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe` or `_activatedRoute.snaphsot.queryParams` provide `queryParams` now.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Did you solve the initial params issue?

Answer (score 9):

I was struggling with the same problem for a long time.
The answer is tricky, in the documentation it was stated:

> ***ActivatedRoute:*** A service that is provided to each **route**
>    component that contains route specific information such as route parameters, static data, resolve data, global query params, and the global fragment.
>   This is mentioned in [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#basics-summary)

The trick answer is **'route component'**, that means ActivatedRoute will work only on components that are routed. In other words only components described in the routing table.

### > Reading the obfuscating official documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html). It mentions 'route associated with a component loaded in an outlet'. We can only guess what is an outlet...

I wrote a little investigative code to research this problem in stand alone app.module.ts:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'comp1',
  template: `<h4>comp1 works</h4>`,
})
export class Comp1 { }

@Component({
  selector: 'comp2',
  template: `<h4>comp2 works</h4>`,
})
export class Comp2 { }

@Component({
  selector: 'fail',
  template: `<div>Wrong URL:{{url | json}}</div> <h4>Failure page works</h4>`,
})
export class Fail {
  private url: any;
  constructor(public activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.url = activeRoute.snapshot.url
  };

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div>Base URL:{{url | json}}</div> <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class App {
  private url: any;
  constructor(public activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.url = activeRoute.snapshot.url
  };
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '1', component: Comp1 },
  { path: '2', component: Comp2 },
  { path: '**', component: Fail }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  declarations: [App, Comp2, Comp1, Fail],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

Try running the module for the following URI:

- http://localhost:4200/2
- http://localhost:4200/1
- http://localhost:4200/a/b/c

Good luck, hope the code is demonstrative.

Answer (score 2):

You also can get params using one line of code.

```
constructor(
private router: Router,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
) { }


this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

check angular documentation, its all there:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
  private service: HeroService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
         let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
         this.service.getHero(id).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
       });
```

Comment: I tried this before but getting undefined when trying to get query string parameter. params is actually empty object.

Comment: is this how you pass the parameter? onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    this.router.navigate(['/hero', hero.id]);
  }

Comment: this way [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{st: 'rec'}" 
I want to get st param

Comment: Then try the new way. you should really read this section on the docs.

Comment: maybe this is your missing part, check the id param in the hero route: export const heroesRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'heroes',  component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];

Comment: you are clearly missing something. please post all the relevant code, or  finish this tutorial. I can assure you it's working great for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117851/discussion-between-avi-and-izupet).

Comment: There is a difference between params and queryParams. params is like url.com/id and query params is like url.com?id=4