# How to pass parameters to routes in angular2.0

Tags: typescript, angular

I am  trying  to  use  the  route  params  but  not  able   to  achieve  it  since  when  i  importing  the   Routeparams  it   shows   errors,,

My  template,

```
    <h6 class="headingh6 nobottommargin"><a [routerLink]="['User',{{detail.firstname}}]">  {{detail.firstname}} </a></h6>
```

My componenet

```
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Route, RouteSegment, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'User', 
templateUrl: './components/society/society.html',
Directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class User  {
id:any;
 constructor(routeSegment: RouteSegment) {
   this.id = routeSegment.getParam('id'); 
   console.log(this.id);   
 }
}
```

Can  someone  help  me

My  routes

```
   import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';

  import {DemoPage} from './demo-page';

  import {User} from './components/user/user';


   export const routes: RouterConfig = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', terminal: true },
   { path: 'login', component:Login },
   { path: 'signup', component:SignUp },
   { path: 'demo', component: DemoPage, children: [
     { path: 'user', component:User },
     { path: 'requests', component:Requests },
   ]}
];

 export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)


  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h6 class="headingh6 nobottommargin"><a [routerLink]="['User',detail.firstname]">{{detail.firstname}}</a></h6>
```

Don't use `[]` together with `{{}}`. Either one or the other, but not both at the same time.

To get router parameters use

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.routerState.params.subscribe(p => console.log(p['id'));
}
```

See also [Get route query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488568/angular-2-rc4-activatedroute-query-string-params)

Comment: What router version are you using? There is no `RouteSegment` in the current router version.

Comment: can have any alternative

Comment: Three are 3 (if you count ngrx router then 4)  different routers for Angular2 and each one in different versions. I updated my answer for the V3.0.0-beta.2 (the most current from the Angular2 team) router. The other two routers from the Angular2 team are deprecated.

Comment: When i runned it  says  error  that  "Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property "

Comment: You need to add `@Component({ ..., directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]`})` on components where you want to use `<router-outlet>` or `routerLink`.

Comment: This  time  it  says  Cannot match any routes: 'demo/society/User/Rahul'

Comment: One of http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bangular2%5d%20%22cannot%20match%20any%20routes%22

Comment: `terminal: true` should be changed to `pathMatch: 'full'`

Comment: You also need such a redirect (default route) within the child routes.

Comment: [routerLink]="['/demo/user',detail.firstname]"

Comment: The error  is   Error: Cannot match any routes: 'demo/user/Dhoni'

Comment: You have no parameter defined in your route. Passing one anyway is not supported. Use something like `{ path: 'user/:id', component:User },`

Comment: Thats great Günter Zöchbauer,finally  got  it

Comment: Can you  please  provide me  the resource from where u learnt  angular2

Comment: http://angular.io, http://github.com/angular/angular, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2, https://www.google.at/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=W0CgV-C_EYLb8AfNzoHIDQ#q=angular2

Comment: Thank you  and  i am  trying  to  upload  image  which is not working can u suggest help

Comment: How should I know :D I don't know what's not working. Your last comment was "finally got it". Please create a new question. I don't know about image upload anyway but there some related questions with answers on SO already.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to read the Querystring param ?

if yes, use this

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
   }
```

in the import you need this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

of course this will work if in the route config you have `/:id`