# initialise an angular2 componenet after going through a _router.navigation

Tags: angular, router

How to initialize an **Angular2 componenet** after going through a `_router.navigation`?

I mean I want to go to component without refreshing the browser but trigger the `onChange` function or the `init` function of the component to have the initial config of my variables.

```
let link = ["componant/" + id+ "/sub/"+id]

this._router.navigate(link)
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello Andrei, I just add the minimal code.

Comment: You can subscribe to router events to know when the route changed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977428/how-to-use-new-navigationstart-angular-router-3-0-0-alpha/37983781#37983781 or subscribe to route params change http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712528/how-to-pass-parameters-to-routes-in-angular2-0