# Angular 2 RC5 - Routing with dynamic values in parameter

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded angular application from RC1 to RC5.

In RC1, I defined routes in app.component.ts:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardContainer, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/dashboard/:id/:name', name: 'DashboardName', component: DashboardContainer }
])
```

And in template, I generated links using:

`<a [routerLink]="[/Dashboard, routeParams]"> ... </a>` where `routeParams` is `{ }`
generates a link 
`<a href="/dashboard">...</a>`

`<a [routerLink]="[/DashboardName, routeParams]"> ... </a>` where `routeParams` is `{ id: 2, name: 'joy' }`
generates a link 
`<a href="/dashboard/2/joy">...</a>`

How can I achieve the same in RC5?

Comment: What kind of parameters are they? Route parameters, query parameters? How do the routes look like?

Comment: route parameters...appended after route path i.e. `/path/2/name` where 2 & name could be dynamic

Comment: So passing route parameters as shown in your question doesn't work? I haven't tried it. I always did as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: it doesn't accept name of routes in app.routing.ts now...only path & componentName..how can I differentiate routes with parameters if using the same prefix i.e. `\dashboard`?

Comment: I see. I somehow assumed it's about parameters (question title). There are no route names in RC.5 only path.

Comment: yes..correct. then how to achieve the same thing which I demonstrated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is something like

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 2]"> ... </a>
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/' + 2]"> ... </a>
<a routerLink="{{'/dashboard/' + 2}}"> ... </a>

<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 2, name]"> ... </a>
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/' + 2 + '/' + name]"> ... </a>
```

assuming `id` and name are router parameter.

Passing an array adds them as query or matrix parameters.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', {id: 2, 'name': name}]"> ... </a>
```

Comment: But, I didn't find if we can put names in route in RC5. it allows only path & component in route definition

Comment: I am explaining my question more...Please check it now & reply.

Comment: it doesn't work... it gives me url like `/dashboard;id:2;name:name` which is not what exactly my url should look like.

Comment: What is "it"? I mentioned for the last example that it creates query or matrix parameters. Your comment shows matrix parameters.

Comment: I tried your last solution to pass id & name in the similar way I was using earlier but it generates `/dashboard;id:2;name:name` which is not what I want. I want url to be `/dashboard/2/name` & if I receive it in component, it should give me value for `id` parameter as 2.

Comment: Just because you pass them without parameter names doesn't mean you can't get them by name. They are applied by position and mapped to their name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712528/how-to-pass-parameters-to-routes-in-angular2-0/38712537#38712537. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters

Comment: But, what if parameters are to be passed using a variable name & if there could be multiple binding? In my question, `routeParams` is a variable having all `key: value` bindings.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by multiple binding. Can you post an example a route definition and a matching routerlink?