# How to get the optional query parameters in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Here is the URL that I want to handle
http://localhost/?id=120&lang=en&search=abc

How can I read these parameters (id, lang and search).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ActivatedRoute from @angular/router, just like any other parameters, no difference with a not-optionnal one.

more info at :
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But while importing ActivatedRoute it is showing an compile time error that Module '"/var/www/public/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ActivatedRoute'.

Comment: You didn't specify what version, ActivatedRoute is only available in RC5,

Comment: How can I get this in RC1?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _router:Router) {
    _router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(
      data => console.log('queryParams', data['st']));
```

See also [Get route query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488568/angular-2-rc4-activatedroute-query-string-params/38560010#38560010)

Comment: I guess for the final release it's ActivatedRoute instead. However how would one get an optional parameter ? e.g. If `lang` is set pet querystring, use it, else fall back to english. As far as I can see, there is no way to know for sure that the current subscription is done for this page, meaning if it's not present it will just wait forever. (RxJs timeouts maybe?)

Comment: You can just subscribe to `route.queryParams()`. AFAIK the callback passed to `subscribe()` will be called on every route change, just `data['someId']` will return `null` when no `?someid=value` or `;someid=value` was present on the route.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was useful!

Comment: `route.queryParams()` seems to be only called when there is a change in the query part. For example lets say I'm having a url `/cats/:page?pagesize=x` if I navigate to the next page, but didn't change the pagesize, the callback won't be called. That's a problem when I have `route.params` and `route.queryParams` and want to call a rest API depending on both. Usually I'd zip them together, but  if my 'callback' for `route.queryParams` might or might not get called, then I'd still need a timeout.

Comment: You could report it as a bug or you subscribe to `router.events` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener/35912966#35912966)  and read the values from `_activatedRoute.routerState`. AFAIR there is also an issue that the values are only available after a timeout (sorry don't remember exactly) I think that's a known issue with an open ticket.