# Angular 2 - Why do ActivatedRoute.params returns empty Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am trying to access the `:id` route parameter in a router guard, but for some reason, it always returns an empty `Object{}`.

Initially I didn't know how to do this, so I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488568/get-route-query-params) to point me in the right direction, however it yields no result. The key difference between that and this is that my issue is in a `guard`.

This is my route declaration `app-routing.module`:

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "dashboard/:id",
        component: dashboard.DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [guard.LoggedInGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "home",
                pathMatch: "full"
            }, 
            ...
```

And this is my guard `existsInDatabase.guard` (I tried both `params` & `queryParams`):

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) { }


canActivate() {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.params);
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(param=> {
        console.log(param); // logs empty Object{}
        console.log(param['id']); // logs undefined
    });
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(param=> {
        console.log(param); // logs empty Object{}
        console.log(param['id']); // logs undefined
    });
    return true;
}
```

The issue occurs when I try to navigate from

> `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/136364285`

to:

> `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/136364285/dock/1654321`

How do I get `136364285`?

Comment: I don't have a real solution for this but while you don't have a real answer, maybe you can use "this.router.url.split('/')[4]" to get the id. Hope someone will save you :)

Comment: @Powkachu Thanks, I am thinking that maybe Günter was right (he deleted his answer) That for some reason the param has not yet been 'integrated' into the router...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by passing the following through to the `canActivate`function in my guard.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log(route.params['id']); // logs 136364285
    return true;
}
```

Originally I was getting `route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` in the constructor and even though I was using `.snapshot`, it was not yielding the intended result. No I recieve the route I am **about** to navigate to and can retrieve params from there.