# Angular2 Trigger router.navigate to refresh a page

Tags: angular

I have noticed that using :

`router.navigate(['my-route'])` doesn't work if I am already on `'my-route'`

However, I am looking to refresh the component if I am already on the its route.

What's the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036498/angular2-router3-cant-reload-refresh-active-route

Answer (score -1):

use `router.navigateByUrl` instead

can get url with

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
         this.paramsChanged(params['id']);
       });
    }
```