# How to tell subscribers to retry

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have 2 divisions, for example divisions Left and Right, the server side urls for these divisions are the same except for the division name for example:

```
'/api/Left/DoThisThing';
```

or

```
'/api/Right/DoThisThing';
```

I have this in my `HttpService` (simplified):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private baseUrl = '/api/';
    private selectedDivision: Divisions = Divisions.Left;

    getAll(): Observable<Test[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + Divisions[this.selectedDivision])
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'An unknown server error occurred while trying to get all.'));
    }

    selectDivision(division: Divisions) { this.selectedDivision = division; }
}
```

Of course, the problem is that calling `selectDivision(Divisions.Right)` does nothing until I click on the nav link that forces the child component that subscribes to `getAll()` to reload.

The way I'd prefer to do this is to notify all subscribers of `getAll()` to retry that endpoint... or perhaps cause that `get` request to retry with the newly updated url. How do I do it? If there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use the [**retry**](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) *operator*?

Comment: thanks for your comment, and no I have not, can you please give an example in the context of the question? Where/how would I call this? I just tried adding `this.getAll().retry();` to the `selectDivision()` method and that didn't do anything

Comment: You can pass the number of attempts that you want to the `retry`, ex: `retry(3)`.. otherwise it will be executed indefinitely. Check [**this**](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/catching-rejections/retry.html).

Comment: no, this didn't work either, this seems like a deal for the initial call, I need more like a `forceNewRetry()` or something like that

Comment: I ended up using a hack to get around this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44580036/550975 but would love to see a valid response to this